# Refresh with parameters in the Kendo UI Grid with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, kendo-grid

I'm trying to use the Kendo UI Grid with AngularJS, where I define the grid like in:

```
<div id="grid" kendo-grid="grid" k-options="gridOptions" />
```

I then set the options in the controller, like in:

```
        $scope.gridOptions = {
            height: 543,
            scrollable: {
                virtual: true
            },
            sortable: true,
            dataSource: {
                type: 'json',
                serverPaging: true,
                serverSorting: true,
                pageSize: 100,
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: '/C99_JsonService/F20_GetTrattativePerRicercaConFiltro',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        data: {
                            idvenditore: 9,
                            stato: $scope.statomacchina,
                            esito: $scope.esitotrattativa
                        },
                    }
                },
                schema: {
                    data: function(result) {return result.Data || result;},
                    total: function(result) {return result.Total || result.length || 0;}
                }
            }
        };
```

As you can see, I have some other custom parameters, to use in the request, and they are tied to angular variables as well.
On first load things go well, and I get the right data.
Then, I added a button to refresh the grid with the new values that the user has edited in the UI, tied to 'esitotrattativa' e 'statomacchina'.
I tied to the button the following function:

```
$scope.esegui = function () {
    $scope.grid.dataSource.read();
    $scope.grid.refresh();
};
```

When I click the button (executing function 'esegui'), the request is again sent to the server, but with the original values in the variables, even if I see that the actual values in the parameters are changed: it looks like there is some optimization that uses cached values...
Or am I missing anything important?
Thanks to everybody.
Andrea

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to send parameters when you do a read like this

```
$scope.esegui = function () {
    $scope.grid.dataSource.read({foo:42});
};
```